# Get data from viewpager in activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-cardview

I am using a viewpager to show some editext

[image]

In the picture the red rectangle is my fragment and the blue one is my activity

in my activity i implement my fragment like this

**myAtivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
... 
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    CardFragmentPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new CardFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), dpToPixels(2, this));
    ShadowTransformer fragmentCardShadowTransformer = new ShadowTransformer(viewPager, pagerAdapter);
    fragmentCardShadowTransformer.enableScaling(true);

    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    viewPager.setPageTransformer(false, fragmentCardShadowTransformer);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    ...
```

**CardFragmentPagerAdapter**

```
public class CardFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter implements CardAdapter {

private List<CardFragment> fragments;
private float baseElevation;

public CardFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, float baseElevation) {
    super(fm);
    fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    this.baseElevation = baseElevation;

    for(int i = 0; i< 3; i++){
        addCardFragment(new CardFragment());
    }
}

@Override
public float getBaseElevation() {
    return baseElevation;
}

@Override
public CardView getCardViewAt(int position) {
    return fragments.get(position).getCardView();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragments.size();
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return CardFragment.getInstance(position);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    Object fragment = super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    fragments.set(position, (CardFragment) fragment);
    return fragment;
}

public void addCardFragment(CardFragment fragment) {
    fragments.add(fragment);
}

}
```

And all the edit text i am using it in `CardFragment` a standard fragment

my question is how to use the data of the fragment edit text in my activity

I user this tutorai to perform this viewpager https://rubensousa.github.io/2016/08/viewpagercards

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using interface callback:

Add this new interface:

```
interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClicked(int position);
}
```

In your fragment(s):

```
private OnItemClickListener listener;
```

Also, add a function to set this listener:

```
public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

Finally in your **Activity**:

```
pagerAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

implement the interface on your Activity:

```
class MyActivity extends --- implements OnItemClickListener
```

override its method:

```
void onItemClicked(int position) {
    //do what you want in your Activity
}
```

Final Step:

Set Activity as the listener for Fragment when you are instantiating them for your ViewPager:

```
//this == getActivity()
MyFragment.newInstance(this)
```